# PyInstaller - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, python-venv, auto-py-to-exe

I'm not too familiar with using PyInstaller but I have been trying to use it to convert my .py files to a single exe. I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.10.5 and PyInstaller 5.2. My files look like the following:

```
Scripts Folder

       -venv Folder

       -Dependent Files Folder

       -main.py

       -1.py

       -2.py

       -3.py 

       -4.py
```

I am able to create an exe using 'pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py' in the console and move it from dist to the main Scripts folder. Once I launch the exe I get the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEIXXXXX\palettable\colorbrewer\data\colorbrewer_all_schemes.json'. I've also tried using auto-py-to-exe and get the same issue.

When I check that directory I don't see a folder 'palettable' in the _MEIXXXXX folder (hence the error), but I'm not sure how to add it to that directory. I do see 'colorbrewer_all_schemes.json' in the venv folder within the same _MEIXXXXX folder but the exe can't find it there. I can't add it manually cause it is a temp folder and a new _MEIXXXXX folder will be generated each time I launch the exe again. I've also made sure the library 'palettable' is installed in the virtual environment and in console.

As I say I'm not too familiar with converting .py files to .exe so any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. I still don't know why it couldn't find the palettable library but I was able to get it working by putting this in the command window:

pyinstaller --collect-data palettable --onefile main.py

This allowed it to I guess collect it manually though I'm still not sure how it wasn't able to find palettable in the first place since its installed the same way as all the other dependent libraries. Hopefully this helps anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct by pressing the checkmark. This way, the system knows your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In... Termux...., It doesn't work

```
pyinstaller --collect-data paletable -F writer.py
120 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.0.0
120 INFO: Python: 3.11.5
130 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.10.136-android12-9-27102101-abX900XXU5BWH6-aarch64-with-libc
132 INFO: wrote /storage/emulated/0/editer/writer.spec
136 WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'paletable' as it is not a package.
138 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/storage/emulated/0/editer']
271 INFO: checking Analysis
272 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
272 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
275 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
304 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1043 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
1135 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2664 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4115 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4222 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4222 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 205, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 189, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1033, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 973, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/editer/writer.spec", line 8, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 466, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 574, in assemble
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 774, in get_python_library_path
    imported_libraries = get_imports(compat.python_executable)  # (name, fullpath) tuples
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 240, in get_imports
    return _get_imports_ldd(filename, search_paths)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 322, in _get_imports_ldd
    p = subprocess.run(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1948, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ldd'
~/.../shared/editer $
```

I don't know what should I do....

...yet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).